# "Consider the bear that/which scratches his head." Which is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, which-that

If I wish to say something along the lines of

> Consider the bear *that* scratches his head.

It seems to me that I could instead say

> Consider the bear *which* scratches his head.

I am unsure which of these is correct, if it even matters.

Does anyone know a rule which makes this clear?

Comment: Dupe of [“When should 'that' be used instead of 'which'?“](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309/), which is itself a dupe of [“When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'?“](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/)

Comment: The title of this question, at least, suggests that this question is not about proper usage, but about if getting it wrong ever actually _matters_ which I don't think it does. This would make it not a dupe.

Comment: @Seamus: sure, but then again, there are the words "correct" and "rule" in the body of the question. And the accepted answer sounds like a rather strict rule; at least it's not at all "about if getting it wrong ever actually *matters* which I don't think it does". (ShreevatsaR's and nohat's comments do address that, but they are not part of the answer as it stands.)

Comment: I am sorry for the partial dupe, I tried searching around, but I guess I still missed them.

Comment: Entirely not your fault, BBischof, the site search [doesn't really work](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/37/) for quite a few stop words.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*That* is restrictive, it limits / restricts / specifies the identity of the subject.  Using your example, the bear that scratches his head refers to one specific bear -- "the bear that scratches his head".

*Which* is non-restrictive, meaning it refers to something incidental about the subject.  "Consider the bear, which scratches its head" refers to the bear (could be a single bear, could be the species), which *happens* to scratch its head.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: ShreevatsaR has pointed out that this is a convention, not a grammar rule.  In the end it doesn't "matter", use the convention if it appeals to you.  [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PP1&ots=nYxVmez4W1&dq=merriam%20webster%20dictionary%20of%20english%20usage&pg=PA894#v=onepage&q=that%20which&f=false) is MW's take (thanks, nohat).

Comment: This is not an actual rule of English grammar, just a convention that some people have chosen. Using "which" for restrictive clauses (e.g. "the bear which scratches its head") is *extremely* common in English, by many good writers. Follow this convention only if it appeals to you; it's not a part of grammar.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR That is interesting. Do you have a citation for this? (I'm not testing you, I *am* truly interested).

Comment: Just wanted to add the obligatory language log link echoing ShreevatsaR, one article among many: http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000918.html

Comment: ShreevatsaR is correct. [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PP1&ots=nYxVmez4W1&dq=merriam%20webster%20dictionary%20of%20english%20usage&pg=PA894#v=onepage&q=that%20which&f=false) is the relevant page in *Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage*.

Comment: Of course, the Language Log is silly too; if editors at some publication do want to enforce this strange convention (and some do), it's perfectly their prerogative to do so; Geoffrey Pullum acts like a silly "grammar nazi" in the sense of insisting that grammar must be the only thing that ever decides what gets used.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Fair enough, my grammar nazi English teacher drilled that convention into my head years ago.  It doesn't really matter which you use, one could be understood either way.

Comment: Ah carp! Well now what should I do about acceptance of this answer :/

Comment: I'll add ShreevatsaR and friends' info into the answer

Answer (score 1):

What the other answers have said about "which" having to be used with commas (or in non-restrictive clauses) is wrong. "Which" has long been used by respectable writers in restrictive clauses as well. And when it's used in a restrictive clause, it's wrong to use a comma before it. There's a separate question about this: [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which/96#96)

> Consider the bear which scratches his head.

This sentence does sound wrong, but for another reason. "Which," whether used restrictively or nonrestrictively, has a strong tendency to be used with inanimates. For this reason, "which... his" sounds bad, because "which" implies you're thinking of the bear as an object, or at least as a not-very-animate thing, while "his" implies you're thinking of the bear as a person, or at least as a somewhat animate being. "Consider the bear **who** scratches his head" would be better, or, as the other answers mentioned, you could use "that" and say "Consider the bear **that** scratches his head." (In general, ["that" is not as common as "who" when referring to people](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47039/can-the-word-that-be-used-to-refer-to-people), but either is grammatical.)

ShreevatsaR in a comment mentioned a third option, "the bear **which** scratches **its** head." This doesn't sound as clashingly bad to me as "which scratches his head," but it also doesn't sound as good to me as any of the alternatives I listed in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

One practical, grammatical difference is that, in writing, 'which' will be preceded by a comma (or other visual pause).

Comment: Is this true?! If this is in fact correct, thank you for pointing this out, as I had no idea. :/ +1 for now, but can you give a reference? Not that I think you are lying, but I am a bit paranoid now with respect to colloquialisms vs rules. This site is making me ever more nervous.

Comment: http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/which-versus-that-advanced.aspx ; http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas.htm ; http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/ ; http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/which.htm

Comment: Speaking of commas, my usage above is visually hilarious and I can barely follow it.