# American English: which vs that

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english, which-that

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which)

We've had an American Americanise some phrases for us (with the point of teaching children English), e.g:

UK English: There’s a little white dog **which** lives on the second floor.
US English: There’s a little white dog **that** lives on the second floor.

But there are three sentences which were not altered. We would rather not have a mixture of that and which to make things less confusing for the students. The sentences that were not changed were:

I really like this pencil case which Rose gave me.
There’s a store near here which is open all night.
This is a really cool picture which I brought with me from Little Bridge.

Should these be changed to **that**, or should we change the other sentences that have already been translated back to **which**?

Comment: That which we know, we know which that is, said that witch that bewitched me. (sorry)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which) or [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/that-or-which-does-it-matter) or [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309/when-should-that-be-used-instead-of-which) or [that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15372/which-versus-that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a native speaker but at school I was taught that you should use "that" for defining relative clauses, whereas both "which" and "that" are allowed for non-defining
relative clauses.

Therefore:
"I really like this pencil case which Rose gave me."
Here, the relative clause only adds information about a pencil case that is already known
(this pencil case). In this case, as far as I know, you can also use "that".
The relative pronoun cannot be omitted.

"I really like the pencil case that Rose gave me."
Here the relative clause defines the pencil case: I am talking about the pencil case
that Rose gave me, not about another one. In this case, it is compulsory to use "that".
Alternatively, you can omit "that" altogether:
"I really like the pencil case Rose gave me."

This is at least the rules that I recall from school and I may be wrong.
I also do not know if the American and the British use differ on this since I am neither
from Great Britain nor from the United States.

Comment: Not a native speaker either, but from what I've read in many Q&A here about _which_ vs _that_, this is the reverse of what you say! _which_ and _that_ are interchangeable for restrictive clauses: "the case that..." or "the case which...". _which_ is mandatory for non-restrictive clauses: "this case, which..."