# "This cake, what is my favorite, makes me happy"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage, which-what

Lately I have heard many people using *what* in place of *which* in adjectival phrases:

> - This cake, what is my favorite, makes me happy.
> - This cake, which is my favorite, makes me happy.

Is the first usage grammatical?  Which is the preferred usage?

Comment: This needs context.  Neither sounds correct without it.

Comment: I've heard `In here, what is blah blah blah`, but this doesn't sound correct to me, I have also used `In here, which is blah blah blah`. Which is correct?

Comment: How about giving an pair of example sentences?  I think I see what you're driving at, but I can't give an answer without a bit more clarification of your point.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Which" or "what"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73329/which-or-what)

Comment: @DavidM, "The cake, what is my favorite." or "The cake, which is my favorite." Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Much better.  I will answer below.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["That" or "which"? Does it matter?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/that-or-which-does-it-matter)

Comment: Possibly dialectical. "I wish to complain about this parrot what I purchased not half an hour ago from this very boutique."

Comment: @MετάΕd  Oh, you mean the Norweigan Blue?  He must be pining for the Fjords!  Also, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify we're speaking of two different constructs using which or what as part of an adjectival phrase:

> This cake, which is my favorite, is very fattening.

vs

> This cake, what is my favorite, is very fattening.

*Which* is clearly the better usage in this scenario.

I've certainly seen *what* used in this way (as a replacement for which), but I believe it to be a colloquial usage.  Merriam-Webster calls this usage [chiefly dialect](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what).

I believe this usage to be chiefly in dialects of BrE (and perhaps Southern AmE).

Comment: What? ... Right.

Comment: I've only heard it used facetiously, as in *The Play What I Wrote*.

Comment: @TimLymington As Meta points out above, Monty Python uses it non-facetiously. Probably dialect.

Comment: I'm not sure Monty Python used *anything* non-facetiously; that usage is certainly not to be taken seriously.

Comment: @TimLymington Well, perhaps less facetiously than some of their other dialogue. But, they were excellent at capturing dialect (even if it was for the purposes of parody).