# "that is" or "which is"

Tags: which-that

I am writing an article in BE and I try to remain formal.
I have a difficulty with that and which: (meaningless sentences)

> We move from our old car to the truck **that** is his new means of transportation

or

> We move from our old car to the truck **which** is his new means of transportation

Also,

> This being said, we remark that the datum **that** is θ evidently corresponds to the complement

or

> This being said, we remark that the datum **which** is θ evidently corresponds to the `complement

I think which must be used because it is for a subject like truck and datum here.

Comment: And nTuplicate of several other earlier posts.

Comment: Try this link http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/that-or-which-does-it-matter